# Top 3 to see/do in Reykjavík

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, recommendations, iceland, activities, reykjavik

I am travelling because of my job, and in a few months I'll go to **Reykjavík**.

I'm very excited because it is my first time in Iceland, and I'm managing in having more or less **one free day** to spend as leisure time.

Which are the top-three things/places/activities that I cannot miss in this City (or around the city but nearby)?

Comment: Not yet closed?

Comment: Personal top list: Jökulsárlón & Fjallsárlón (glacier lagoons), Þingvellir (continental rift, lake), Hraunfossar (waterfalls, also worth in winter!), Glymur (highest waterfall), Skaftafell (with Svartifoss), Geysir, Dyrhólaey (bird nesting grounds), Systrafoss in Kirkjubæjarklaustur, Grænavatn (few km south of Reykjavík), Elliðaárdalur (beautiful nature **inside** Reykjavík), Esja (the mountain across the bay when looking from Reykjavík). Extras: hike around Viðey, whale watching tour towards Hvalfjörður. Don't miss out on the hot tubs, but skip the Blue Lagoon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of possible day trips from Reykjavik to explore the surrounding area.  If you only have the chance to do one I would suggest the [Golden Circle](http://www.re.is/DayTours/Details/1346), the tour will pick you up from your hotel and return you to it at the end of the day.  During the day you will see geysir - the water spout that others are named after.  Whilst geysir doesn't erupt any more strokkur next to it goes off every few minutes and is an impressive site.  It also stops at Gulfoss which is a beautiful waterfall, and Þingvellir national park - a lovely lake where two tectonic plates meet.

I did this tour in 2009 and really enjoyed it, and from the website it doesn't look like things have changed massively.

Another thing you might be able to fit in on the way to/from the airport is the blue lagoon - some companies offer a single ticket from Reykjavik to the blue lagoon to the airport at keflavik.  It is a relaxing geo-thermally heated pool, but is fairly pricey.

Comment: Actually the Blue Lagoon is more like the *waste water* of a geothermal power plant. Ever cared to take a hike around it? If now, you should. The picturesque place isn't quite so picturesque anymore from the back ... or if you walk/drive a little further towards Grindavík.